# Adding a custom launcher to Unity

Tags: unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)

I understand that I should be able to right-click on my Unity desktop and select 'Create Launcher'.  I don't have that menu option.  Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org): Xfce has very elegant support for this through the **menu editor**.

Answer (score 1):

This option yet is not available, but you can create a desktop launcher in ~/.local/share/applications or in /usr/share/applications where you can see several examples.